# Tensorflow Keras - feeding input to multiple model layers in parallel

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

With tensorflow.keras (Tensorflow 2), I want to feed my input into different layers of my model. So we are looking at a graph where the input layers branches off into 3 lines to go to 3 different convolutional layers. It has 3 outputs.

Pseudocode is something like this:

```
inputs = Input()
conv1 = Conv2D()(inputs)
conv2 = Conv2D()(inputs)
conv3 = Conv2D()(inputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[conv1, conv2, conv3])
```

But I'm getting the following error when I try to fit the model with a tf DataSet stream:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), for inputs ['conv2d_1', 'conv2d_2', 'conv2d_3'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>]
```

I have verified that my code works fine if I comment out the branches and set `outputs=conv1`.

Note: I am not trying to feed in multiple different inputs (there are many questions and answers on here that solve this). Just one input which should branch off.

Comment: Just while I work on it, I think I may know the problem. I'm not providing 3 sets of labels, and I think the optimisation routine is trying to find that even though I want the labels to all be the same.

Comment: Yes, if you don't provide a 3-array of labels that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. I should be providing a 3-array of labels.